# Can the value of CoreApplication.MainView or CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher change in runtime?

Tags: uwp, dispatcher, mainview

I execute some action in main UI thread.
I used for it CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.
Do I need to get CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher every time?
Or I can get it one time when the application starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the `CoreApplication.MainView` will not be changed. But there are some scenarios like you are using multiple views with [ApplicationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/application-view). Relying on MainView will cause breaks if the app ever has more than one view.
If you don't have multiple views in your app, that will be fine.